# My Freemarker cannot pass object to templates

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat, freemarker

I'm learning the Freemarker framwork and I have this question.
Can i pass a custom object to template files? I saw these post that they do what I have said, but it not working for me.

[Passing a List of Objects to Freemarker and then Looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981495/passing-a-list-of-objects-to-freemarker-and-then-looping)

http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_datamodel_objectWrapper.html

I know spring can help me, but i want to try without it.

My code is this:

Servlet:

```
public class servletTest extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
 */
public void init(ServletConfig servConfig) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        cfg = config.getConfig();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


/**
 * Questa chiamata permette di chiamare il file di configurazione per il
 * template
 */
private Configuration             cfg;




protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();



     SimpleHash root = new SimpleHash();
     // expose a "simple" java objects:
     root.put("theString", "wombat");
     // expose an "arbitrary" java objects:
     root.put("theObject", new banquet( "Thinking In Java") );


    /* Get the template */
    Template template = cfg.getTemplate("banquetsList.ftl");

    Writer out_template = new StringWriter();

    try {

        template.process( root, out_template );

    } catch (TemplateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    out.write( out_template.toString() );



}



}
```

Config file:

```
   private static void build_config() throws IOException{


    cfg = new Configuration();

    cfg.setServletContextForTemplateLoading( R.context.get_servletContext(), R.path.get_TEMPLATE() );

    DefaultObjectWrapper ObjectWrapper = new DefaultObjectWrapper();

    cfg.setObjectWrapper( ObjectWrapper.DEFAULT_WRAPPER );
    cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.HTML_DEBUG_HANDLER);
    cfg.setIncompatibleImprovements(new Version(2, 3, 20));




}
```

banquet class:

```
class banquet{

banquet( /*int code,*/ String title){
    //this.code = code;
    this.title = title;
}
public String title;
//public int code;

 }
```

Template file:

```
<html>

<body>

    <h1>
        lista di banchetti
    </h1>



    <div>

    </div>

    <div>


               ${theObject.name}
    </div>



</body>
```

I have wrong or Freemarker has a bug? yes i'm noob but this problem joke me...

Thanks all beforehand :)

### **SOLUTION**

I found the solution!
I had add PUBLIC to banquet bean and I put setter and getter methods thanks for all :)

Comment: Any changes in the template file? Or only need to make bean public and add setter and getters is enough.
Can you please share the solution?